# Scan multiple ESP8266

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, http

I am working on wifi based LED project which involves various ESP to be connected to router. Basically grouping of ESP has to be done. The android app sends HTTP command to IP address which is given by router to the ESPs, the IP are not static and expires after some time. Now my question is how can mobile app can get the IP of all the ESP connected to router?

Does using HTTP protocol complicates the process? Shall I switch to multicast UDP? or use UnPn Protocol for scanning (Sounds complicated though).

Please help!

Comment: HTTP is a 1:1 connection. If you want 1:many you need a different protocol. Multicast UDP is possibly the best way to go - then the ESPs subscribe to the multicast address and you don't care what their IPs are.

Comment: So how exactly UDP works? The packets sent to multiple ESPs at once reaches at the same time? For example I am sending value of RED led 254 to 6 ESP, all 6 ESP will glow to RED at once?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast

Comment: And who creates the multicast address? Router? or A master ESP is needed?

Comment: That link tells you.

Comment: This may also help: http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=2464 - it's wonderful what you find on Google...

Comment: It is said that UDP is very unreliable protocol. Packets get lost. How can I make sure they are sent and if not sent, receive feedback and retransmit again.

Comment: With great difficulty. It is best if you create your system in such a way that it doesn't care if you lose a packet or two.

Comment: Anyway, UDP isn't *very* unreliable. It's "unreliable" in that there is no built in mechanism for guaranteed delivery. It doesn't mean that packets go astray all the time.

Comment: Okay, I understand that.

Comment: @Majenko Can I use this app for testing multiple ESPs?? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hastarin.android.udpsender&hl=en

Comment: Possibly. Try it and see. Personally I use `nc` on Linux.

Comment: Any option to use with Macintosh?

Comment: Not from me. `nc` (NetCat) may be available in homebrew, or it may not. You'll have to look for yourself. Or ask Google, which contrary to popular belief, isn't my name.

Comment: Hahaha, Okay!! By the way, you are not any less than Google

Comment: I would go with UDP broadcast, since multicast may need to be set up correctly.

Comment: @Paul What is the difference between UDP multicast and broadcast? What is the advantage of using it over multicast?

Comment: With multicast it'll get switched to specific groups, broadcast will go to every UDP server on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with UDP Multicast.

Answer (score 1):

The best protocol for these kind of applications is MQTT.

Read more [here](http://mqtt.org/)

Comment: MQTT has delay. I need instant response within milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Multicast is the only option.

Comment: Can you back up your answer with some explanations please?